# Media player playing multiple files at the same time

Tags: android, media-player

I am having a problem where once the user clicks on a sound to play from my ListView, then while that sound is playing they click on another sound, the 2 sounds they clicked play at the same time.

I would like to have the sound that was currently playing, finish, then start the new sound that they most recently clicked.

If someone could help me, that would be much appreciated!

CODE:

```
ListView BoardList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BoardList);

    String List[] = {

     "Audio1", "Audio2", "Audio3", "Audio4", "Audio5"
         , "Audio6", "Audio7", "Audio8", "Audio9"
           , "Audio10", "Audio11", "Audio12" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listcustomize, R.id.textItem, List);

    BoardList.setAdapter(adapter);

    BoardList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
            if (position == 0) {



                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio1);
                mPlayer.start();
            }

            if (position == 1) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio2);
                mPlayer.start();

            }
            if (position == 2) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this, R.raw.Audio3);
                mPlayer.start();

            }
            if (position == 3) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio4);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
            if (position == 4) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio5);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
            if (position == 5) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio6);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
            if (position == 6) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio7);
                mPlayer.start();
            }

            if (position == 7) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer
                        .create(HodgeMain.this, R.raw.Audio8);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
            if (position == 8) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio9);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
            if (position == 9) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio10);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
            if (position == 10) {


                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio11);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
            if (position == 11) {

                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                        R.raw.Audio12);
                mPlayer.start();

            }
```

Comment: Unsolicited advice => It's usually a sign that code can be written more efficiently when you're repeating the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Media player playing multiple files at the same time
```

**Try**

Declare `MediaPlayer mPlayer;`  common for all

**Like**

```
BoardList.setAdapter(adapter);
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
```

then use `mPlayer.release();`

```
if (position == 0) {

    if(mPlayer!=null)
    {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer=null;
    }

    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
            R.raw.Audio1);
    mPlayer.start();

}
.
.
.
.
if(position==N)
{
        if(mPlayer!=null)
        {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer=null;
        }
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HodgeMain.this,
                R.raw.AudioN);
        mPlayer.start();
}
```

**About  `release():`**

`Releases resources` associated with this `MediaPlayer object`.

It is considered good practice to call this method when you're done using the `MediaPlayer`.

In particular, whenever an `Activity of an application is paused (its onPause() method is called), or stopped (its onStop() method is called)`, this method should be `invoked to release the MediaPlayer object`, unless the application has a special need to keep the object around.

**PS.** i have tried with `release()` which is working fine !

**Example: which is working for me**

```
try {

if (position == 1) {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.all);
    mPlayer.start();
}
if (position == 2) {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.all2);
    mPlayer.start();
}
}

catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When I add that code before "mPlayer.start" it does not fix the problem.

Comment: @Jack try Updated answer !

Comment: I've updated my code in my answer so you can see if I have done everything correctly. For some reason, the audio files are still playing over each other.

Comment: @Jack no you are not using `reset()` double match my updated answer !

Comment: Also, I get a warning "Dead code" with "mPlayer.release(); }" underlined. Mind, I only get this on the first position and not the other positions.

Comment: Yes I have, for some strange reason, whatever I call before the ".create" seems to be non-existent to the code even though it's there.

Comment: @Jack check my updated answer with example which is working fine for me !

Comment: Would you know why I am getting "Dead code" on " mPlayer.release();
                      mPlayer = null;
                  }" ?

Comment: I've google'd the error and people are saying to ignore it. Anyway, thank you for your help and time. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Before it's start consider doing the following:

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) mPlayer.stop();
mPlayer.start();
```

Implement it inside your `if` statements and see if it works for you!

But for this to work you have to define your `MediaPlayer` object in a wider Scope and not declaring everytime a new `MediaPlayer` object.

Comment: For some reason the app crashed when I do this.

Comment: Post yor stack trace then to see why it crashed!

Answer (score 0):

as already mentioned, you need to instantiate the `MediaPlayer` class using `new` to access its object anywhere in your class and not statically like you are doing it now. I'm pretty sure consulting this document will help you understand more about the `MediaPlayer`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the static method MediaPlayer.create(); is actually returning a new instance of MediaPlayer for you.

The reason multiple are playing is because you're not stopping the previously playing audio file (as others suggested).

Call this method IMMEDIATELY BEFORE calling MediaPlayer.create():

```
private void killSounds(){
    try{
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //Eat it and do nothing because it's just going to be an NPE when mPlayer is null, which doesn't matter because we're handling it
    }
}
```

After you've stopped the previous MediaPlayer, you should be able to create the new one without the sound overlap.

Comment: It's still overlapping each other when I play them when I use this. Also, I have to remove the "private void killSounds(){" because it throws me errors.

Comment: If you're getting an error on that, then something else entirely is very wrong with your code. You're running all of that in a static method, aren't you?