# Android Media player onClick issue

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using `MediaPlayer` for playing sounds `onClick`. Until the sound is finished the click event is not play the sound again. How can it play the sound again on click, when the sound is currently playing?

```
final MediaPlayer mistake = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.mistake);

tv_mistake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mistake.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: so you want to hear two three..etc sound when the button is pressed??

Answer (score 1):

You must create a new `MediaPlayer` object to play the sound again like so.

```
tv_mistake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mistake != null) {
            mistake.release();
            mistake = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.mistake);
        }
        mistake.start();
    }
});
```

You can read more about MediaPlayer in the following links.

Also a quite similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362886/media-player-playing-multiple-files-at-the-same-time)

[MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), [MediaPlayer Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.html), [MediaPlayer Tutorial From Google](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-simple-audio-app-in-android-part-1-3-c14d1a66e0f1)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to play the sound even if the sound is still playing

Comment: @Y.Glik check now

Comment: @Y.Glik Did it work ? If yes then Please mark the answer as acccepted if it helped.Thanks.

Comment: its working, but if click more then 10 times it stop playing the sound..

Answer (score 1):

Most of the errors in `MediaPlayer` comes due to improper handling of different [states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) of its object.

You should release `MediaPlayer` object after completing playback or before calling `start()` again.

> It is also recommended that once a MediaPlayer object is no longer being used, call release() immediately so that resources used by the internal player engine associated with the MediaPlayer object can be released immediately.

Create a `MediaPlayer` object as:

```
Mediaplayer mediaPlayer = null;
```

And call `playMistakeSound()` on button click:

```
tv_mistake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        playMistakeSound()
    }
});
```

Implement `playMistakeSound()` as:

```
void playMistakeSound() {
    try {
        // releases MediaPlayer object before calling create() again while previous is still playing
        if (mediaPlayer != null){
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity() /*Context*/, R.raw.mistake);
        // this will release MediaPlayer as soon as it completes
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log exception and handle
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```