# Android how to play another raw file and while mediaplayer is playing a raw file?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Does anyone know how to play another raw file, while a raw file is playing?
Currently, i can play and pause one raw file thats store in the drawable folder. 
Heres my current code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_soundtrack);

    playButton = findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
    nextButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    prevButton = findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Soundtrack.this, R.raw.ost1);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(ButtonPress == false)
            {
                player.start();
                playButton.setText("Pause");
                ButtonPress = true;
            }
            else if(ButtonPress == true)
            {
                player.pause();
                playButton.setText("Play");
                ButtonPress = false;
            }
        }
    });

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play media files of a list in sequence then consider the link-
[Media player playing multiple files at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362886/media-player-playing-multiple-files-at-the-same-time)

If you want to play two or more media file at the same time you have to create two or more instances of MediaPlayer and call the start on both instance.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use the same mediaplayer to stop playing the current media file, and play another media file?