# Why mediaPlayer.stop(); is not working here?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

**[AS]** I've loaded two sounds that can play and overlap with no problem, however I can't seem to stop or pause them.

In its current state, the stop button only writes to a log, but I can't seem to get mediaplayer.stop(); or mediaplayer.pause(); to work.

To be clear, I want stopSound to end all sounds currently playing and have each sound start from the beginning when called again.

Is volumeControl creating a conflict? Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    AudioManager audioManager;

    public void playSound(View view) {

        Button soundButton = (Button) view;

        Log.i("INFO", soundButton.getTag().toString() + " button pressed.");

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(soundButton.getTag().toString(), "raw", getPackageName()));

        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void stopSound(View view) {

        Log.i("INFO", "stop button pressed.");   

        mediaPlayer.stop();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_01);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_02);

        SeekBar volumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        volumeControl.setMax(maxVolume);
        volumeControl.setProgress(currentVolume);

        volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

                Log.i("Seekbar changed", Integer.toString(i));

                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, i, 0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context="com.example.company.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonL1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:onClick="playSound"
                    android:tag="sound_01"
                    android:text="Sound One" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonR1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:onClick="playSound"
                    android:tag="sound_02"
                    android:text="Sound Two" />


            </GridLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="stopSound"
            android:text="stop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/seekBar" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try using this  if media player. stop() not work       try {
                var audioManager =  mContext!!.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0, 0);
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code like below:-

MediaPlayer mediaPlayerOne;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayerTwo;

```
public void playSound(View view) {

        Button soundButton = (Button) view;


        mediaPlayerOne.start();
        mediaPlayerTwo.start();
    }
```

You are trying to stop a media player instance which is not started yet. You are playing a media player instance which is local to that method.

In oncreate method like below:-

```
mediaPlayerOne = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_01);
mediaPlayerTwo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_02);
```

When stop:-

```
 mediaPlayerOne.stop();
 mediaPlayerTwo.stop();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solves most of my problem. It's stopping the sounds, but only the very last one that was initiated; any already-playing sounds don't respond to the stop button. (eg. I press sound_01 and sound_02 in quick succession, both sounds play simultaneously, I press stop, only sound_02 stops, sound_01 continues until finish).
Do you know how I can fix this to stop all sounds?

Comment: If it solves your issue, please upvote and mark as an answer. It may be helpful for others.

Comment: Create two global instances of media player and stop each one while taping stop button

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this.. I want to add many more sounds to this setup so would not want to create a media player for each one as that would probably cause processing issues.. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362886/media-player-playing-multiple-files-at-the-same-time